# Analysis regarding definite integration of $\int_3^6 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x+\sqrt{x}}} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-numbers

I have been fiddling with this question for quite some time.
There are some queries that popped up in my head.
The general queries are:

1. If using real analysis we find out where the function gives real values and we plot the graph, and we see, the function isn't real everywhere, does that ensure that in the parts where it's not real, **it has to be** complex valued? In other words, does a function ALWAYS have to be either real valued or complex valued? Can it be not the case where it's neither of the two?
2. what is the graphical significance of area under a curve being complex(or imaginary ie containing $\sqrt{-1}$)?

Now coming to the problem, I tried using traditional methods to analyze the function, however, I got the graph of the function only until the real part, which is in between zero to about $2\sqrt{2}$ from what I understood.

1. I tried desmos, which gave the real plot. I tried wolframalpha for the complex plot. It showed up what I expected.
2. wolframalpha shows that the definite integral will yield a complex value.

I have considered the possibility of this being a lazy question conversion from indefinite to definite (since complex area yielding functions are technically not in the scope of the course I am in). However, with that too, it is yielding a complex area, which **I'm not sure** will yield the same value as the one wolframalpha gave. Basically what I did, was probably criminal, but I didn't consider if the function is defined over the interval $(3,6)$.
I got the answer of the indefinite integration of the said function as
$$\frac{-(4\sqrt{x}+6)(\sqrt{-x+\sqrt{x}+1})-7(\arcsin{\frac{2\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{5}}})}{4}+c$$
Plugging the upper and lower limits of integral into this, gives a complex value, which is understandable, given the function isn't defined there.

I would love to get some insights into this and how to solve this. It would be of great help.

Comment: It's probably a typo. Either the bounds were meant to be $[0,1]$ or the denominator was supposed to be $\sqrt{9-x}+\sqrt{x}$. Those were the most likely alternatives, but it could be others, too, where the answer stays real.

Comment: Yes, that was an error on my part, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Azlif that was a mistake on my part, I've corrected that. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @NinadMunshi yes, that's what i felt too, however, i just wanted to know about the complex parts. it was more of a general query arising out of a specific problem. Thank you for the insight.